# /dev directory; characteristic device files: network_latency, network_throughput

Tags: devices

I'm using some networking devices for car to car communication which runs on Linux 3.10.17 OS. With those devices I've to measure the overall network throughput and latency. Inside the /dev directory, I've found two characteristic device files named as "Network_Throughput" & "Network_Latency". Now.I would like to know that is it possible to measure the overall network throughput and latency using those two files?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside they have been removed in [4.4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4a733ef1bea705cdc69d936b95fedab4b47fbd40), those were used for [Power Management Quality of Service](https://elinux.org/images/f/f9/Elc2008_pm_qos_slides.pdf), not monitoring.